Существует ли такое слово, как "несловарный"?
Может ли в данном случае приставка -не образовывать новое слово? Дело в том, что такого слова в орфографическом словаре Лопатина я не нашёл, также не нашёл я его и в НКЯ, вернее, нашёл, но всего лишь одно употребление на весь национальный корпус. Однако в интернете много статей, объясняющих значение данного слова с примерами.

Спасибо за приемку ответа. Что-то вы редко  заходите, хотелось бы вас видеть чаще)

Читать ваши ответы - одно удовольствие.)

Спасибо!  Изящный комплимент))  Тогда я жду ваших новых вопросов)


Словарный — относительное прилагательное, образованное от сущ. словарь.

Большой толковый словарь русского языка. СЛОВАРНЫЙ см. Словарь.
СЛОВАРЬ, -я; м. 1. Книга, содержащая перечень слов, расположенных в определённом порядке (обычно по алфавиту), с их толкованиями или с переводом на другой язык. Составлять с. Готовить с. к изданию.  2. только ед. Совокупность слов, используемых кем-л. или где-л. Обогатить свой с.  Словарный, -ая, -ое. С-ая статья. С-ое издательство. С. состав языка (слова и устойчивые словосочетания; лексика языка).
Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой:
Словарный, прил. 1. Относящийся к составлению и изданию словарей словарь. 2. Лексический.

Но слова несловарный  в словарях у Кузнецова и Ефремовой нет. Значит ли это, что такого слова нет и писать НЕ слитно не следует?

По правилам Лопатина и Розенталя такое возможно, если в заданном тексте подразумевается противопоставление. Условно говоря, все множество слов этом случае  мы делим на две части (словарные и несловарные) и обозначаем непринадлежность слова к словарным.

Примеры по этой теме лучше посмотреть в Карте слов, так как они относятся к специальной лексике.  Там же указаны значения слова несловарный в Викисловаре.

В обычной литературе несловарный используется в переносном смысле (= неприличный):


И, к моему изумлению, разбив сразу мое восторженно-благоговейное настроение, Тургенев произнес обнаженное несловарное слово. Н. М. Минский, «Три часа у Тургенева», 1921 г.
И на каждые три слова два несловарных, или наоборот, в зависимости от обстоятельств... Б. Окуджава, 1985 г.
ПРАВИЛО
ПАС под ред. Лопатина, § 148.
С существительными, прилагательными, наречиями на -о отрицание НЕ пишется слитно в следующих случаях.
 2. Если существительные и прилагательные в сочетании с НЕ 
 обозначают непринадлежность к какому-либо разряду лиц или 
 явлений, напр.: неврачи, нефраниузы, немарксисты, 
 нехристиане, неспециалисты, немосквичи, нерусские, 
 недемократы, непоэты, нетермины, неметаллы, нестихи; 
 Нерусский взглянет без любви / На эту бледную, в крови, / 
 Кнутом иссеченную музу (Некр.);  неакадемические институты, 
 непищевые добавки, невоенные отрасли.

